Confused about the meaning of それと実質勢力下の青州の連合軍 here
*Fullsentence 俺たち、幽州と徐州、それと実質勢力下の青州の連合軍は、同じ計画を抱えた同盟となって、平原を出発した。
I'm having trouble to understand this sentence , while play a game similar to dynasty warrior. Hope someone could help me understand its correct meaning if i was wrong.
My 1st understand but not sure : "We, the allied forces of Youzhou, Xuzhou, and Qingzhou, which is under our actual control , set out from the plain as an alliance with the same plan in mind."
(I also confused about this kanjis part 実質勢力下の青州の連合軍 , so the main army is 青州 , including the army of protagonist + army of other province 幽州と徐州 ?? I mean who's control who here ?? Hope someone could explain this aspect too)
*More note: in this story, the protagonist is an advisor of LiuBei (at this time Liu Bei is still a Chancellor of 平原/Pingyuan/the plain), so the army of 青州 province is in reality under their control ? Or they're working under the command/control of 青州 province's army ??
According to wiki, i found 青州 province in ancient china has 5 commanderies, namely 平原/ Pingyuan, Jinan, Beihai, Qiansheng, Donglai, and the kingdom/principality of Qi.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Qingzhou_(ancient_China)

There are several ways to parse this sentence, and it's impossible to determine which one is correct without fully understanding the story.
One of the most straightforward interpretations would be:
The allied forces of:
  1. Us (俺たち),
  2. 幽州,
  3. 徐州, and 
  4. 青州, which is under our actual control

Technically, it's equally possible to parse it like:
1. We (俺たち),
2. 幽州,
3. 徐州, and 
4. the allied forces of 青州, which is under our actual control

It's even possible to parse it like this (though less likely):
1. Us 幽州 and 徐州, and
2. the allied forces of 青州, which is under our actual control

Your interpretation seems to be like this, but I feel it's unlikely, if not impossible:
1. We, and
2. the allied forces of:
   - 幽州,
   - 徐州, and
   - 青州, which is under our actual control

If you understand the relationships between these factions, it should be possible to choose the correct one.

I guess i will go with "We (main character's and his party army in 平原/ Pingyuan) + together with the armies of these 2 provinces 幽州と徐州, which in reality/essentially are all under command of 青州 province's army. I still not sure though since i'm not native Japanese, purely based on the kanji 下 means "under someone/something"
